# Can't create a project in .NET Framework 4.7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to create a new Azure WebJobs project targeting .NET Framework 4.7 but it's not available in the drop down -- see below:

[image]

And if I try to install .NET Framework 4.7, I get the message that it's already installed on my computer -- see below:
[image]

Any idea why?

P.S. This may or may not be relevant but my ultimate objective is to create a WebJob that can use class libraries that are created in .NET Core 2.0. If I understand it correctly, .NET Framework 4.7 can use class libraries that support .NET Standard 2.0. I didn't necessarily do anything special when I created my class libraries in .NET Core 2.0. Not sure if I should assume they automatically target .NET Standard 2.0 or I need to specify it somewhere.

Also, the version of Visual Studio I'm using is Visual Studio 2017 - 15.3.3

Comment: No, VS Installer doesn't give me such an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the 4.7 Framework Developer Pack, not just the framework itself. If you are using Windows 10 with the latest updates it will show up in the installer for Visual Studio, if you do not have it you can install the SDK manually [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168).

That being said, if you are writing stuff in .NET Core 2.0 you don't need .NET framework 4.7, you need .NET Core 2.0. Go install [that SDK instead](https://aka.ms/dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-gs-x64) so you can create .NET Core 2.0 programs.

Comment: The link you provided worked which was for the .NET Framework 4.7 Developer Tools. Running .NET Framewor 4.7 installer was giving me the message in the original post. As per your second comment, we cannot YET create WebJobs in .NET Core which is why I'm trying to install .NET Framework 4.7 so that I can create the WebJobs in .NET Framework and be able to use my class libraries created in .NET Core. Anyway, thanks for the link and your answer. I was able to install .NET 4.7.